# ReactProxy error:Could not proxy request /api from localhost:3000 to http://192.168.0.8:4000. Before it was ECONNREFUSED after few tries --> ETIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, reactjs, proxy

I'm doing e-com project in react. But suddenly after some-time when started npm start in react it throws me an error like

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/v1/products?keyword=&page=1&price[gte]=0&price[lte]=25000&ratings[gte]=0 from localhost:3000 to http://192.168.0.8:4000.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ETIMEDOUT).

Proxy error: Could not proxy request /Roboto-Regular.ttf from localhost:3000 to http://192.168.0.8:4000.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ETIMEDOUT).

Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/v1/me from localhost:3000 to http://192.168.0.8:4000.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ETIMEDOUT).
```

My **package.json** of react

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.61",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "overlay-navbar": "^1.2.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-alert": "^7.0.3",
    "react-alert-template-basic": "^1.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.3",
    "react-material-ui-carousel": "^2.3.11",
    "react-rating-stars-component": "^2.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-toastify": "^9.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "webfontloader": "^1.6.28"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start ",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://192.168.0.8:4000"
}
```

My package.json of backend(server)

```
{
  "name": "e-com",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "backend/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node backend/server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon backend/server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "cloudinary": "^1.30.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.4.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.5.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.8",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "validator": "^13.7.0"
  }
}
```

I tried several answers from stack-overflow like adding (a slash) "proxy": "http://192.168.0.8:4000/",
killing the tasks of node server in the task manager. Restarting the system again. Nothing worked!
All it changed to ECONNREFUSED --> ETIMEDOUT
Any help, please!

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of countless searches. I forgot that, Ip address which I had given in the react package.json wasn't dynamic one. I'm finally able to do it. I just change my proxy to "proxy": "http://localhost:4000"

Answer (score 0):

Only when saving a file in the client folder, both create-react-app's auto-reload and nodemon's auto-reload kick in. I believe this is creating a race-condition for the proxy at the frontend as both servers are temporarily down when restarting. If nodemon restart first then proxy works. If not, componentDidMount and fetchUser in App dispatch the action too earlier... Which is why sometimes it works, sometimes it crashes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try placing your proxy before the private object like this:
"name": "frontend",
"version": "0.1.0",
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
"private": "false",

Comment: Hello @Holeey , Could you provide more details why the solution of switching between the order of the two keys will solve the problem?